# Visual Studio : set number of project build in parallel from command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, parallels

I’m using Visual Studio 2010 devenv to build solutions with command line ( NOT using MSBUILD ), 
Visual Studio is set to build up to 8 projects in parallel ( it was set on Visual Studio IDE under Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run )
But I have one solution that for it I don’t want to build ANY projects in parallel.

Is there a way to set the max number of project being built in parallel from command line for a specific solution ?

If not maybe I can change the number of projects set in VS through the registry and undo the change after the solution was built  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this if you build on the command line using devenv, but you can with msbuild. If you have existing scripts that call devenv then it's quite simple to change to msbuild:

Instead of:

```
devenv  solution.sln /build Debug
```

Use:

```
msbuild solution.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug
```

You can then add the flag `/m:N` to specify the maximum number of concurrent processes to use for the build (eg `/m:4`)

Comment: worth looking at https://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx

Comment: Watch out though, that page is over 9 years old. The current msbuild (in VS2017) still accepts the `/m:N` flag.  Note also that there is a separate flag to the compiler that you can pass, 'Multi-processor Compilation', `/MP`, that I think is independent of the msbuild flag.

Comment: MsBuild does not support Intel Fortran projects. If you have any in your solution, you're forced to use devenv. The question is about how to set the number of project build in parallel from command line - AFAIK it's not possible in devenv.